# Number() provides names space to parseint() in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
console.log(Number('234'));
console.log(Number.parseInt('234x', 10));
console.log(Number.parseFloat('234.2', 10));
```

**Number()** provides **names space** to parseint() in javascript.

So you should you parseInt() in this format:

```
Number.parseInt('234x', 10)
```

instead of like this:

`parseInt('234x', 10)`

If i use any of the below mentioned ways and if it doesnt matter  then why does this give different results.

```
Number.isFinite('23') // False

isFinite('23') // True
```

What does it mean by Number provides names space to **parseInt()**, **parseFloat()** etc.

Comment: Have you tried reading [the MDN page for `Number.isFinite()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite) where the answer is explicitly spelled out in the *Description* section?

Comment: "*Number() provides names space to parseint() in javascript.*" - are you quoting that sentence from somewhere, if you don't understand what it means? If yes, please provide the source of the quote.

Answer (score 1):

The [MDN documentation for `Number.parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseInt) says

> This method has the same functionality as the [global `parseInt()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):
>
> ```
> Number.parseInt === parseInt // true
> ```

Same for [`Number.parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/parseFloat):

> This method has the same functionality as the [global parseFloat() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):
>
> ```
> Number.parseFloat === parseFloat; // true
> ```

---

For [`Number.isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isFinite), the story is different:

> In comparison to the [global `isFinite()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite), this method doesn't first convert the parameter to a number.

Same for [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN):

> In comparison to the [global `isNaN()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), `Number.isNaN()` doesn't suffer the problem of forcefully converting the parameter to a number.